# Riddle Number Six

Tags: riddle, cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

Fiddle diddle diddle, time for another riddle. This is another little puzzle I've concocted for you all this evening. The scenario is this:

You awake in a small room with only one door. The door is sealed with a padlock, whose combination happens to be represented by letters. There are three letters needed to unlock the door. Inside the room with you is a table with a note and a chessboard. The note reads as followed:

> -.-. .- ...- . .- .. .-. . .-.. | 75
>
> .--. ..- -... ... -.- .. | 110
>
> .-. . - --- .-- | 86

The chessboard is different than most, for it has numbers from 1-26 and random letters on the board:
[image: Riddle Chessboard]

So the riddle is to solve the padlock code and free yourself from this room. Whoever shall solve the riddle first will receive a small bounty of my own reputation. Good luck.

Comment: any chances of a hint?

Comment: The Morse Code translation and the numbers next to them will aid you in this puzzle. Solve those two conundrums and the rest will be easy.

Answer (score 2):

Partial:

Hashes and Dots:

> Translating from Morse Code -->: 
> "CAVEAIREL", "PUBSKI", and "RETOW". 
>  They are anagrams of CAVALIERE, BISKUP, and TOWER 
> They are Knight, Bishop (in Polish), and Rook respectively (Credits @rhsquared & @Braegh)
> (NOT: The words can be further divided into "Cave, Air, El, Pub, Ski, Re, Tow".)

Chessboard

> may refer to a Caesar Square, and 1-26 may be mapped to letters (Credits @rhsquared)

Comment: The Morse Code deciphering was easy enough, but what do the words mean? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Further to the Morse code translation done by @OmegaKrypto:

> I think the words might be anagrams.
>  CAVEAIREL -> CAVALIERE
>  PUBSKI -> ?  (might be the Yiddish word BUPKIS which emphatically means nothing)
>  RETOW -> TOWER

Regarding the chessboard:

> It is worth noting that the numbers go from 1 to 26 which probably means that they are mapped to letters.

Comment: You are very close with the Morse translations. Two of them are indeed correct, however, bupkis is not. Also, why would I put such words in Morse? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to the Morse code translations:

> PUBSKI is an anagram for BISKUP, which happens to be Polish for "bishop"; a chess piece. Similarly, "cavaliere" -> knight and "tower" -> rook.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on what @rhsquared and @OmegaKrypton said
I think:

> CAVEAIREL -> CAVALIERE = Knight
>  PUBSKI -> Biskup = Bishop(?)
>  RETOW -> TOWER = Rook
>  I still don't know what the numbers mean, I tried adding up the value of each ie. a=1,b=2, but no success

so

> maybe we need to follow their move (diagonally, across or knight move) on the chessboard

as for the letters and numbers

> we have all the numbers 1-26
>  we only have 11 letters: N, R, E, U, Z, G, K, V, P, A, X

Comment: Pirate, you are beginning to earn my respect! You have the clues, now you just need to put them together! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing what other people pointed out (thanks everybody), I guess we should start to put:

> - Knights on cells numbered 7 and 5.
>  - Bishops on cells numbered 1 and 10.
>  - Rooks   on cells numbered 8 and 6.
>  I tried to evaluate all possible positions of these pieces but it does not seem to make me advance. 
>  Cells that cannot be reached are: 13, 22, 23, 24, 20, 19, A, X.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the info shared by @yaara

> By trying to move from number 1 to number 26, in sequence, there are 11 times where you cannot get to the next number using a legal move from either a rook, knight or bishop. In each of those cases you can however use a single letter (or a choice of one of a few letters) as an intermediate step. There is at least one sequence where each letter is used exactly once as an intermediate step.

This does not yet address the numbers next to the Morse code words.

Some thing else to note is that

> all letters are on light squares.